# Python: Search word on a given webpage

Tags: python

This is my first program using python for the web.
I want to count the number of occurrence of a specific (e.i: football), on google and fifa home page.

1) On Google

```
def wordOnTheWebGoogle():
    import urllib2
    import re    
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
    print re.findall("football",page)
    print page.find("football")
```

Output is

[]

-1

2) On Fifa home page

```
def wordOnTheWebFifa():
    import urllib2
    import re    
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.fifa.com").read()
    print re.findall("football",page)
    print page.find("football")
```

Output is

```
wordOnTheWebFifa()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-4e40573ed4fb>", line 1, in <module>
    wordOnTheWebFifa()

  File "D:L12Problem.py", line 21, in wordOnTheWebFifa
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.fifa.com").read()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Forbidden
```

I thought at least google search would have returned something, but none. 
Could someone help me to solve both issues? 
For the Fifa.com, why this forbidden message.

Regards,
Adjeiinfo

Comment: "I thought at least google search would have returned something, but none. " It did return something. why none?

Comment: Sorry, but without a basic understanding of how HTTP / the Web works, you won't get this to work. Your problem has nothing to do with Python: You're never actually doing a Google search. You're retrieving Google's front page, and searching for the word `football` on that page.

Comment: The next thing is: It's a violation of Google's ToS to use it to search that way, and you *will* get banned if you execute search queries by scraping instead of using their API.

Comment: Just to make in clean: the OP does not want to "search the web", he wants to search in a given page. The title is misleading.

Comment: bereal, thank you. I changed the tile to search on a given page.

Comment: Even so, the implication is that the OP thinks he has searched google for 'football'.  He is searching the page returned by "www.google.com" for the word 'football'.  Unsurprisingly, the word 'football' does not appear on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

- You are not finding the word "football" at "www.google.com" because the word "football" does not appear on that page.  Load `www.google.com` in your browser and see if you can see the word "football".

If you want to search the page that google returns when you search for "football", you emulate pressing the "google search" button on that page.   As you will see if you view the source of google.com, finding the form fields in amongst that huge blob of code and working out how to submit them is non-trivial.   And as observed in comments, it may violate terms of use.

Question 2:

- It is mysterious why urllib2 fails to load www.fifa.com.  I can't see anything that you are doing wrong - it does the same for me. About the only thing I can think of us that urllib2 is not providing some header info that the server at fifa.com demands, so the request is being rejected (because the "Forbidden" error seems to be telling us that it's fifa.com that is refusing our connection).

I would recommend you use a better library for doing web access.   This does what you want:

> ```
> import requests
> import re
> def wordOnTheWebFifa():
>     page = requests.get("http://www.fifa.com").text
>     print re.findall("football", page)
>     print page.find("football")
>
> wordOnTheWebFifa()
> ```

Result:

```
mgregory$ python foo.py
[u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football', u'football']
2569
```

Comment: I guess you're just modifying the code in the question, but **please** don't put import statements into functions like that (unless you have a **very** good reason). Put them at the top of the program, where they belong.

Comment: Yeah - I just went with the minimum change from what the OP had.   Fixed.